# How to get the row index of selected checkbox on grid GXT

Tags: checkbox, grid, onchange, gxt

I am working with GXT (2.2.5) and need to get the row index of chenged checkbox on the grid. What i am doing is to create a grid and apply a GridCellRender to show a checkBox in first column, then when any checkBox change their value (listener at the OnChange event), the row index of changed checkbox must be taken. This is a part of my code by the moment:

```
    checkColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Object render(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore store, Grid gri) {
            final CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
            check.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    //Here we get the row index
                }
            });
            return check;
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
 checkColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Object render(final ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, final ListStore store, Grid gri) {
            final CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
            check.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    //////////
                    int indx = store.indexOf(model);
                    //////////

                }
            });
            return check;
        }
    });
```

(note that you must convert to final your *store* and *model* variables)

Or maybe this:

```
checkColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Object render(final ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, final ListStore store, Grid gri) {

            final CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
            check.setData("indx", store.indexOf(model));

            check.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    //////////
                    int indx = ((CheckBox) be.getSource()).getData("indx");
                    //////////

                }
            });
            return check;
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps

Comment: its not working :\ i dont know hoy it supose to be but im just using that gridCellRenderer to add the checkbox for each row. My grid use a Object called Facultad (that i created).

Comment: Notice that you may see the store and model variables as null while debugging due to the variables types... but the method must give you back the index

Comment: Does something like this helps you?: grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

Comment: That line works with the selection, but when i activate or desactive the checkbox, the row its not selected, just the checkbox. Thats the reason i cant get the index.